# Authorize Roles MVC web from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I got the below compilation error when I added "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADGroupReader"].ToString()" to the authorize role section header.

In the web.config I have:
    add key="ADGroupReader" value="Readers DEV"

Compilation error: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

```
[AuthorizedRedirect]
[Authorize(Roles = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADGroupReader"].ToString())]    
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    .....
}
```

I do not want to hard code the role (Roles="Readers DEV"); I would like to read it from the web.config. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

This [attributes tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx) explains attribute parameter restrictions:

> Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values of the
>   following types:
>
> - Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
> - string
> - System.Type
> - enums
> - object (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of one of the above types.)
> - One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types

From description above, this assignment is invalid due to existence of `ToString` method:

```
[Authorize(Roles = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADGroupReader"].ToString())]
```

As a workaround, you can create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` with predefined `Roles` parameter which contains default assignment to `Roles` with your `AppSettings`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute() 
    {
        this.Roles = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADGroupReader"].ToString();
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

Usage in controller class:

```
[AuthorizedRedirect]
[CustomAuthorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it this way

Created a derived class ReaderAuthorizeAttribute

```
public class ReaderAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public ReaderAuthorizeAttribute()
    {            
        this.Roles = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADGroupReader"];
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Then added [LoteReaderAuthorizeAttribute]

```
[AuthorizedRedirect]
[ReaderAuthorizeAttribute]    
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Just a little finetunning: In the last part, the attribute in the class must be [ReaderAuthorize] and not [ReaderAuthorizeAttribute]. The seccond one will not make the software fail, but for me was allowing everybody to log without checking.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this the following way, allowing you to define the setting name the roles value should come from:

```
public class AuthorizeBySettingAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeBySettingAttribute(string setting) : base()
    {
        if (setting != null && Settings.Default[setting] != null)
        {
            this.Roles = Settings.Default[setting].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("AuthorizeBySetting initialized with invalid setting");
        }
    }
}
```

In my case I'm getting the value from a generated Settings class, but you can just change Settings.Default to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.